# rails3: action being routed to the wrong controller. Possible bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rails-routing

I have two models (user & profile) with a 1-to-1 association.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :language_tokens, :tele, :languages, :serviceDesc, :service
  belongs_to :user
  ...

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

The profile is built using:

```
@profile = @user.build_profile(session[:form_params])
```

my profile edit form is just a standard form which should be routed to my profile update action upon submission.

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/host_information', :f => f%>
  <%= render 'shared/service_information', :f => f%>
  <%= f.submit 'done', class: "bnt"%>
<% end %>


HTML form:
<form id="edit_profile_6" class="edit_profile" method="post" action="/profiles/6" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

However, for some bizarre reason, the form is being submitted to **user** update instead of the expected **profile** update. I put a debug point in user update and you can see that the params confirm that the target controller should indeed be profiles_controller.

```
/railsapp/loco_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:82
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
(rdb:15) p params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"qXx5EWwIWASiARKVFE7eDd43gHnBSmK538YAXeesDyI=", "profile"=>{"country_id"=>"8", "city_id"=>"22", "tele"=>"", "language_tokens"=>"18,14", "service"=>"9",  },
"commit"=>"done", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"profiles", "id"=>"6"}
(rdb:15)
```

here are the relevant routes:

```
profiles POST   /profiles(.:format)                   profiles#create
new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)               profiles#new
edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)          profiles#edit
profile PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)               profiles#update

users GET    /users(.:format)                          users#index
POST   /users(.:format)                          users#create
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#show
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                      users#destroy
```

What's the best way to debug this problem? Is this some weird side-effect of a 1-to-1 association or is there a bug here? I'm using rails 3.2.2.

****UPDATE****
So this definitely looks like a bug. I regenerated my controller (same name) and copied over the same code and now it's working without any other changes. I'm still interested in knowing whether this is a known issue and how to debug problems like this in the future.